# Unit test instantiation of class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I wrote a wrapper class around the Cassandra driver module and I'm in the process of writing unit tests for it. I can unit test that a particular method of a class was called (e.g. `connect`). However, asserting that this was called is not enough. I want to make sure that the params passed to my wrapper method (i.e. `open_session`) when I instantiate the class are the ones I expect.

How can I unittest the instantiation of a class before any method is called upon it?

My wrapper class:

```py
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

class CassandraWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, hosts, port):
        self.session = self.open_session(hosts, port)

    def open_session(self, hosts, port):
        cluster = Cluster(contact_points=hosts, port=port)

        return cluster.connect()
```

My unit tests:

```py
from cassandra_wrapper import CassandraWrapper
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest

class TestCassandraWrapper(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect')
    def test_open_session(self, connect_mock):
        cw = CassandraWrapper(['localhost'], 9042)

        connect_mock.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: You need to fix your invalid code before you can test it. `self` isn't defined at class level.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Fixed now @DanielRoseman